# Where is `vino-preferences` gone in Xubuntu 13.10? (sharing desktop in Xubuntu 13.10)

Tags: xubuntu, vino

I just switched from Gnome to Xubuntu (adding the `xubuntu-desktop` to my laptop) because I decided that with an Atom processor and 2G of RAM the full gnome shell experience is a bit, well, slow.

All is ok but for the remote desktop sharing.

I can activate `vino-server` correctly [following these instructions](http://webhostingneeds.com/Enable_remote_desktop_in_xubuntu) (or similar --- there was the entry in the session manager already), so far so good.

The problem is that `vino-preferences` has been removed from the `vino` package (1)--- see [this bug report](http://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=729468) for more info. It says (in Spanish) that now the vino preferences have to be set from the "Sharing->Desktop Sharing" in `gnome-control-center`. I have the `gnome-user-share` package installed.

But under Xubuntu running `gnome-control-center` gives just a minimal thing (correctly, I think), and I cannot find any way to reach the preferences settings of `vino`.

By the way, the server works (I am connected with it now), thanks to the fact that I had the preferences set up from the previous Gnome desktop session... but how can I access them in Xubuntu?

(1) See:

```
(1)asus-romano:~% dpkg -L vino | grep pref       
(1)asus-romano:~%
```

although:

```
(1)asus-romano:~% apt-file search vino-preferences
app-install-data: /usr/share/app-install/desktop/vino:vino-preferences.desktop
vino: /usr/bin/vino-preferences
vino: /usr/share/applications/vino-preferences.desktop
vino: /usr/share/vino/vino-preferences.ui
```

...probably referred to some older package.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using `gsettings`:

- List all configuration keys:

  ```
  gsettings list-recursively org.gnome.Vino
  ```
- To set a value of a key, example `view-only`:

  ```
  gsettings set org.gnome.Vino view-only true
  ```

`gsettings` comes with `libglib2.0-bin` package. You may need to restart vino service to apply the new settings.

Comment: Will try tomorrow as I will be back to my little laptop. I used `dconf-editor` to try to find the keys, without success, but I suspect the search could be case-sensitive... And I searched for `vino`. Grrrr....

Comment: Yeah, It seems like `gsettings` have other option to store data some where else then `dconf`.

Comment: Effectively --- I really though that `dconf-editor` were a graphical interface to the same data base than `gsettings`... time for another question?

Comment: The `vino` settings are in `dconf-editor` under org.gnome.desktop.remote-access (see http://askubuntu.com/questions/416556/shouldnt-dconf-editor-and-gsettings-access-the-same-database)... so yes, search in dconf-editor is case-sensitive (with IMHO is *almost* a bug).

Comment: As I can see, dconf-editor mentions same schema `org.gnome.Vino` but not as path `/org/gnome/Vino` like a mapping. Nice to learn new things. Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

For anyone still confused by this, Vino used to have the handy configuration tool called 'vino-preferences' until about 2014, but that was removed when gnome-control-center became able to control it instead.

Discussion on that decision here: https://forums.bunsenlabs.org/viewtopic.php?id=1411

There are many distributions which can usefully use `vino-server` (which is an excellent VNC server), such as Lubuntu - being based on LXDE, that doesn't use `gnome-control-center` and there's little reason to install such a big block of code just for one solitary function.

Instead, to access the `vino-server` configuration just install `dconf-editor` to control it:

```shell
sudo apt-get install -y vino dconf-editor
```

CONFIGURATION:

a. Open `dconf-editor`, then:

b. VNC settings can be accessed under `org -> gnome -> desktop  -> remote-access`

SECURING VNC ACCESS over SSH

For those wanting to pipe VNC through an SSH tunnel for secure remote access, you can use a command from the client end to open the tunnel:

```shell
sudo ssh -g -L 0.0.0.0:5900:127.0.0.1:5900 your_username ip_of_your_remotemachine
```

This means "SSH, please open a tunnel to ip_of_your_remotemachine and make a TCP connection from it, out to 127.0.0.1:5900 (i.e. its own port 5900 where `vino-server` is listening), and tunnel all traffic back to me / I'll mirror it out of :5900 locally - thanks".

You then open your VNC client (try the excellent Remmina) to your local address:port (ex. 127.0.0.1:5900, which is mirroring the listening port at your remote server now) and VNC opens, giving you remote desktop.

Read separately on turning off passwords for your SSH server and use keys only, for highest security.