# Adjust text scaling factor for all users

Tags: text, scaling

I am using gnome tweak tools on my system which is Ubuntu 12.04 with a few users set. I want to change the text scaling factor for all the user accounts.

If I use `gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.interface text-scaling-factor 0.7` does the job fine but only for the user that is issuing the command. The rest of the users retain their settings which I don't want.

I want to do this from CLI since I am trying to incorporate this later to puppet.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

### Change defaults by editing the original schemas

1. Change default value in Glib schema

   ```
    sudo nano /usr/share/glib-2.0/schemas/org.gnome.desktop.interface.gschema.xml
   ```

   Like:

   ```
        <key type="d" name="text-scaling-factor">
        <range min="0.5" max="3.0"/>
        <default>0.7</default>
        <summary>Text scaling factor</summary>
        <description>Factor used to enlarge or reduce text display, without changing font size.</description>
        </key>
   ```
2. Compile schemas

   ```
    sudo glib-compile-schemas /usr/share/glib-2.0/schemas
   ```

### Changing defaults by creating an override file

Otherwise, because you want an easy way for `puppet`.

1. You can create a dconf override file:

   ```
    sudo nano /usr/share/glib-2.0/schemas/30_my-text-factor.gschema.override
   ```
2. Append override keys & values to it, example:

   ```
    [org.gnome.desktop.interface]
    text-scaling-factor=0.7
   ```
3. Compile schemas

   ```
    sudo glib-compile-schemas /usr/share/glib-2.0/schemas
   ```

The new users and the users uses default (They never changed value or they have reset it) will get the new value effective.

### Force  all users to use defaults using a lock file

If you want to force users to use default value (their customized value has no effect), add a dconf lock:

1. Add new lock file or change an existing one at:

   ```
    /etc/dconf/db/gdm.d/locks/
   ```
2. Append this line to it:

   ```
    /org/gnome/desktop/interface/text-scaling-factor
   ```

**References:**

- [Shouldn't dconf-editor and gsettings access the same database?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/416556/shouldnt-dconf-editor-and-gsettings-access-the-same-database)

Comment: Thank a lot. this works as dreamed. My only issue is that i want to do this from puppet which means i need to make a template out of it and change the value through a variable. Need to try it but it looks feasible.

Comment: @kostasp, then it is better to make an override file instead of changing original schema file `/usr/share/glib-2.0/schemas/org.gnome.desktop.interface.gschema.xml`. See examples: `ls /usr/share/glib-2.0/schemas/*.gschema.override`

Comment: This didn't work for me - I posted a question with my problem here: https://askubuntu.com/questions/723267/gconf-override-schema-error-can-no-parse-as-value-of-type-d

Comment: @RobinWinslow , thank you , I made a mistake. The value  should be without quotation marks. you could delete the other question as there is no need for different answer.

Comment: Ah thanks! I swear I tried that. Never mind. I'm going to leave my question there 'cos I think it adds value by mentioning this error message. Someone might google that same error message (as I tried to do) and find my question.

Comment: @RobinWinslow , good, Me too in doubt, if you check my answer edit history, you see that it was without those marks, and for some reasons I added them later (I forgot why). Btw, if it helps you, you may consider some up votes here for Q & A :), plz make a look on https://askubuntu.com/help/why-vote

Comment: Upvoted. Yeah I know why I should vote, I just forgot to.

Answer (score 1):

I sort of found a working solution working for one user at a time. It looks like if use:

```
su user_name bash -c 'gsetting set org.gnome.desktop.interface text-scaling-factor 0.7'
```

It fails because of:

> x11 connection rejected because of wrong authentication

This is because X win cookie is not carried over. So tried the following steps:

```
root:~#echo $DISPLAY
root output:~#localhost:10.0
root:~#xauth list
output:~#
eglisa-bh/unix:12 MIT-MAGIC-COOKIE-1 9435aa7eb876e2edf3e4f29bbe90f42a
eglisa-bh/unix:10 MIT-MAGIC-COOKIE-1 5e987f3ce693dd4789fgc5c012067f31
root:~#su - student
student:~#DISPLAY=localhost:10.0; export DISPLAY
student:~#xauth add eglisa-bh/unix:10 MIT-MAGIC-COOKIE-1
5e987f3ce693dd4789fgc5c017f31
```

Does the trick and then by running again:

```
su user_name bash -c 'gsetting set org.gnome.desktop.interface text-scaling-factor 0.7'
```

The text scale changes to 0.7 as wanted.

I've tried messing with sudo as well by adding  inside the sudoers file:

```
Defaults env_keep +="DISPLAY XAUTHORIZATION XAUTHORITY"
```

But this also didn't work. If there is any easier way I would really appreciate it.