# gconf override glib schema error - "can not parse as value of type 'd'"

Tags: gnome, display, display-resolution, gconf, glib

I'm trying to override the gconf settings for `text-scaling-factor` and `scaling-factor` on my system, following the method [mentioned here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/469515/adjust-text-scaling-factor-for-all-users).

So I created a file at `/usr/share/glib-2.0/schemas/30-retina-scaling.gschema.override` with this contents:

```
[org.gnome.desktop.interface]
text-scaling-factor="0.75"
scaling-factor="2"
```

But when I try to compile it I get the error "can not parse as value of type":

```
$ sudo glib-compile-schemas /usr/share/glib-2.0/schemas/
error parsing key 'text-scaling-factor' in schema 'org.gnome.desktop.interface' as specified in override file '/usr/share/glib-2.0/schemas/30-retina-scaling.gschema.override': 0-6:can not parse as value of type 'd'.Ignoring override for this key.
error parsing key 'scaling-factor' in schema 'org.gnome.desktop.interface' as specified in override file '/usr/share/glib-2.0/schemas/30-retina-scaling.gschema.override': 0-3:can not parse as value of type 'u'.Ignoring override for this key.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So it turns out it's the quotation marks that mess this up. The contents of the file should be:

```
[org.gnome.desktop.interface]
text-scaling-factor=0.75
scaling-factor=2
```