# Preventing Window resizing after resume

Tags: 18.04

This bug poisons my ubuntu experience. When the pc resumes (re-open the lid) the windows are re-sized. See example below (screenshot) for FF:

[image]

Is there anything I can switch off to fix this?

Comment: I also have this issue.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I had exactly the same problem and I had real trouble finding a solution. Eventually, I solved it by turning off Gnome's automatic window scaling. You can check your current setting with the following:

```
gsettings get org.gnome.desktop.interface scaling-factor
```

If this returns a value of `uint32 0`, then it means you have automatic scaling turned on. I found that setting this to a specific value (in my case 1) fixed the issue, which you can do using the following:

```
gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.interface scaling-factor 1
```

I discovered this by following this answer about [scaling gnome's login screen](https://askubuntu.com/questions/906797/scaling-gnome-login-screen-on-hidpi-display). The problem seems to be caused by a mismatch between the login screen and desktop scaling factors.

Comment: My issue wasn't solved when I set `scaling-factor` to `2`; I'm running Bionic on a desktop with a 4K display on 200% scaling, and widows are resized after I lock the screen and then resume.

Comment: Although I upvoted this answer, this bug is persistent on 22.04

Answer (score 0):

You can upgrade dist too

`sudo apt-get dist-upgrade`

I'm sure this solution is working for you.