# slick greeter with Wayland -- login screen only

Tags: 22.04, wayland, unity-greeter

I've seen a number of posts on Ubuntu talking about how to change global scaling; *not* what I'm looking for. The greeter/login screen on certain HiDPI resolution settings is unacceptably small and I'd like to enlarge without cranking up the scaling globally. I used to accomplish this with slick-greeter but with Wayland/GDM3 these settings seem ignored. Any way to change the greeter resolution to scale 2x without impacting the rest of the gtk (post-login) scaling?

Answer (score 0):

I have solved this issue in a very arcane way, I'm sure there's an easier way to do what I did, but here are the steps I took:

- [Installed gdm-tools](https://www.linuxuprising.com/2021/05/how-to-change-gdm3-login-screen-greeter.html)
- [Followed the steps mentioned in this article](https://askubuntu.com/questions/906797/scaling-gnome-login-screen-on-hidpi-display)
- ran `sudo glib-compile-schemas /usr/share/glib-2.0/schemas` as per the above article, after creating the  file /usr/share/glib-2.0/schemas/93_hidpi.gschema.override with scaling-factor=2
- rebooted, greeting screen was at 200%
- logged in, desktop was also at 200% (not desired)
- settings|displays, set desktop to 100%
- rebooted, now login/greeter screen was scaled 2x but desktop was desired 100%