Desktop settings on the login screen
I know this subject was discussed many times yet I cannot find the working solution.
I have 2 monitor setup and on the login screen I would like to have the same Display settings as on my Desktop.
I have tried to copy the monitors.xml file to /var/lib/gdm3/.config, settings it's ownership to gdm and even uncommenting WaylandEnable=false in /etc/gdm3/custom.conf.
No matter what I will do nothing happens. I use newest Ubuntu 24.04.
I would appreciate all tips or ideas. Thank you in advance.

I have the same issue. Have you found a solution?

Yes and now.  On a laptop the scaling sets properly, on two monitors it is not. I found a workaround on another post. What I did is I have created a file:  /usr/share/glib-2.0/schemas/93_hidpi.gschema.override with the content:
'code' [org.gnome.desktop.interface]
'code' scaling-factor=2'
then run 'code' sudo glib-compile-schemas /usr/share/glib-2.0/schemas
It changes the scaling to 200%. It is not a best solution - only one that worked for me. Here is the original post [link] https://askubuntu.com/questions/906797/scaling-gnome-login-screen-on-hidpi-display
