# Disable HUD menu

Tags: unity, shortcut-keys, hud

I know it may be useful feature for someone, but i don't use it at all.

Is there any way to protect HUD key from beeing set up after every/some update of Ubuntu?

Answer (score 0):

1. You can create a dconf override file:

   ```
   sudo nano /usr/share/glib-2.0/schemas/30_disable_hud_shortcut.gschema.override
   ```
2. Append override keys & values to it, example:

   ```
   [org.compiz.integrated]
   show-hud="['']"
   ```

The new users and the users uses default will have it disabled.

**References:**

- [Shouldn't dconf-editor and gsettings access the same database?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/416556/shouldnt-dconf-editor-and-gsettings-access-the-same-database)

Comment: Will try it and hopefully i'll accept your answer later (if it won't enable) :)

Comment: Unfortunately it had enabled itself again... so cannot accept this answer. The file was left intact (the override one)