# Help tracking down /org

Tags: configuration, directory, dconf

While checking something with `dconf watch` I saw the following path pop up again and again:

```
/org/freedesktop/tracker/miner/files/index-recursive-directories
```

However, when I try to navigate to the `/org` directory, I am told that it doesn't exist. In my root folder there is no such file or directory. I am sure there is some basic thing here that I am not understanding, but what/where is this directory?  Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, it is a path but not regular one. It's in Dconf databases (either user one or system common one)

```
$ file ~/.config/dconf/user 
/home/user/.config/dconf/user: GVariant Database file, version 0

$ file /etc/dconf/db/gdm
/etc/dconf/db/gdm: GVariant Database file, version 0
```

You may use `dconf-editor` which is GUI tool to manipulate user dconf setting. See [Shouldn't dconf-editor and gsettings access the same database?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/416556/shouldnt-dconf-editor-and-gsettings-access-the-same-database), it may help get basic understanding of dconf.

Answer (score 1):

This is not a filesystem path but a dconf path. It specifies a directory within the dconf database and is not related to any file or directory in your file system.