# How to change gnome-terminal profile preferences using dconf or gsettings?

Tags: gnome-terminal, dconf, gconf, gsettings

After upgrading form Ubuntu 14.10 to 15.10, it seems that changing `gnome-terminal` preferences using `gconftool-2` is no longer supported. I guess this issue is related the [Gconf to GSettings migration](https://wiki.gnome.org/Initiatives/GnomeGoals/GSettingsMigration).

Now, I would like to change some of my old scripts ( since they are broken in Ubuntu 15.10 ) to work with `dconf`/`gesettings` instead of `gconftool-2`.

As an example, on Ubuntu 14.10 ( `gnome-terminal` version 3.6.2 ) I could set the number of columns in the `Default` profile using:

```
$ gconftool-2 --set /apps/gnome-terminal/profiles/Default/default_size_columns \
            --type=int 140
$ gconftool-2 --set /apps/gnome-terminal/profiles/Default/use_custom_default_size \
            --type=bool true
```

Now, in Ubuntu 15.10, typing:

```
$ dconf list /org/gnome/terminal/legacy/
```

gives

```
profiles:/
schema-version
```

whereas

```
$ gsettings list-relocatable-schemas | grep Terminal
```

gives

```
org.gnome.Terminal.SettingsList
org.gnome.Terminal.Legacy.Profile
org.gnome.Terminal.Legacy.Keybindings
```

The above output confuses me:

- Why is there a `/org/gnome/terminal/legacy/profiles:/` path for `dconf` but no `org.gnome.Terminal.Legacy.Profiles` (note the trailing `s`) schema id for `gsettings`? Also, see  [Shouldn't dconf-editor and gsettings access the same database?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/416556/shouldnt-dconf-editor-and-gsettings-access-the-same-database) for more information.

Still in Ubuntu 15.10 (using `gnome-terminal` version 3.16.2), if I run:

```
$ gsettings list-keys org.gnome.Terminal.Legacy.Profile:/ | grep default
```

I get:

```
default-size-rows
default-show-menubar
default-size-columns
```

so there is a `default-size-columns` key that could (?) correspond to the `default_size_columns` key in Ubuntu 14.10, but there is no `use-custom-default-size` key corresponding to the `use_custom_default_size` key in Ubuntu 14.10. This also confuses me.

Also, if I try running:

```
$ gsettings set org.gnome.Terminal.Legacy.Profile:/ default-size-columns 150
```

and open a new `gnome-terminal` the setting of `default-size-columns` seems to have no effect since the terminal still opens with 80 columns..

Comment: Please upgrade to 15.10 first, as both 14.10 and 15.04 already reached end of life.

Comment: @ByteCommander I have upgraded to 15.10 now, and the question remains the same w.r.t 15.10 as for 15.04. I also found a solution, that I would like to post. How can this question be reopened, so I can post the solution?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

The syntax to be used with the `gsettings` command is described in 
[GNOME Terminal Frequently Asked Questions](https://wiki.gnome.org/Apps/Terminal/FAQ).

First you need to find out the identifier of the profile you want to change. For example, the identifier of the `gnome-terminal` default profile can be obtained from schema `org.gnome.Terminal.ProfilesList`.

Then change the desired keys of path `/org/gnome/terminal/legacy/profiles:/:UUID/` of schema `org.gnome.Terminal.Legacy.Profile:` for this profile.

*Note the colons in the above path. It will not work if they are omitted.*

Here is a script that use the above to set `default-size-columns` of the default profile:

```
profile=$(gsettings get org.gnome.Terminal.ProfilesList default)
profile=${profile:1:-1} # remove leading and trailing single quotes
gsettings set "org.gnome.Terminal.Legacy.Profile:/org/gnome/terminal/legacy/profiles:/:$profile/" default-size-columns 150
```

Comment: Cool that you found the solution yourself. Don't forget to accept your own answer.

Comment: Actually, you can specify the number of the profile instead of its ID, so the command would be just: `gsettings set org.gnome.Terminal.Legacy.Profile:/org/gnome/terminal/legacy/profiles:/:0/ default-size-columns 150`

Comment: Or even shorter: `gsettings set org.gnome.Terminal.Legacy.Profile:/:0/ default-size-columns 150`

Comment: Your answer saved my day! How did you find out the syntax of "org.gnome.Terminal.Legacy.Profile:/org/gnome/terminal/legacy/profiles:/:.../"? Did you find it in the documentation? What got me stuck was I didn't realize "Profile" should be followed by "/org/gnome/...".

Answer (score 0):

Anatoli's shorter versions did not give me the current value of the column width setting, they returned 80 even though the terminal had been set to 120.
But Hakon's method worked perfectly.

To get the "path" use dconf-editor to locate the profile and click on the profile name and you can then "Copy current path" - see attached screenshot[image]