# How to change the background to use built-in theme from gnome-terminal profile preferences --> Color using dconf or gsettings?

Tags: command-line, 18.04, gnome-terminal, xml

For gnome-terminal --> Edit --> Preference --> profile --> color, I don't want to "use color from system theme" but use "built-in schemes = Solarized dark".

According to this [answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/733202/541417), I am able to use these commands to get the UUID of the profile I want to change:

```
gsettings get org.gnome.Terminal.ProfilesList list
gsettings get org.gnome.Terminal.ProfilesList default
```

Also I can see the UUID of the profile at the bottom right corner of  gnome-terminal --> Edit --> Preference --> profile --> color.

To deselect "use color from system theme", I used this command:

```
gsettings set org.gnome.Terminal.Legacy.Profile:/org/gnome/terminal/legacy/profiles:/:UUID/ use-theme-colors false
```

How do I then use the given "built-in schemes", e.g. "Solarized dark", "Tango dark" via cmdline? I could not find their name in `/usr/share/glib-2.0/schemas/org.gnome.Terminal.gschema.xml`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There are no schemas designed for "Built-in-schemes:"

what is "Built-in-schemes:" doing is, it has pre-configured colors..

for the foreground-color with description "Default color of text in terminal"

for the background-color with description "Default color of terminal background"

So find out the two colors (first choose the Buili-in-schems) for the "Built-in-schems:" with the below commands

note: change the UUID in below commands with your UUID

```
pratap@pratap:~$ gsettings get org.gnome.Terminal.Legacy.Profile:/org/gnome/terminal/legacy/profiles:/:dec6f19d-ac6e-438a-8a48-122429c5c909/ foreground-color
'rgb(131,148,150)'
pratap@pratap:~$ gsettings get org.gnome.Terminal.Legacy.Profile:/org/gnome/terminal/legacy/profiles:/:dec6f19d-ac6e-438a-8a48-122429c5c909/ background-color
'rgb(0,43,54)'
pratap@pratap:~$
```

This means when ever you provide these two rgb colors.. the "Built-in-schemes:" will be changed to "Solarized-dark"

For Example:
If you want to have "Tango-Dark" as the "Built-in-schemes:"

Run the below commands.. Change the UUID with your profile ID.

```
gsettings set org.gnome.Terminal.Legacy.Profile:/org/gnome/terminal/legacy/profiles:/:dec6f19d-ac6e-438a-8a48-122429c5c909/ foreground-color 'rgb(211,215,207)'

gsettings set org.gnome.Terminal.Legacy.Profile:/org/gnome/terminal/legacy/profiles:/:dec6f19d-ac6e-438a-8a48-122429c5c909/ background-color 'rgb(46,52,54)'
```

In the below GIF, I have two terminals open. The left one is the profile with ID starting with "dec6" and the commands I gave in other Terminal with different profile..

[image]

Comment: Thanks. What rgb values do I then use for "Tango dark"?

Comment: Got it.. silly me... :)

Comment: Previously a Ubuntu 16.04 user. EOL coming. So started using Ubuntu 18.04. But have a huge knowledge gap due to Ubuntu 18.04 now uses GNOME not Unity. So have to ask all these questions to better leverage what Ubuntu 18.04 can do.  Painful... but really appreciate all the help given. :) I think many others face the same questions as me... and will benefit from all your answers too... ;)

Comment: In case anyone wants to know Tango dark settings, they are: `foreground-color = 'rgb(211,215,207)'` and `background-color = 'rgb(46,52,54)'`