# workspaces setting in filesystem

Tags: unity, gnome, workspaces

I'm trying to find the location of the config file for gsettings, specifically referencing the number of workspaces. I know the commands:

```
gsettings set org.compiz.core:/org/compiz/profiles/unity/plugins/core/ vsize 3
gsettings set org.compiz.core:/org/compiz/profiles/unity/plugins/core/ hsize 3
```

but where is the file which these commands change?  I did a search using

```
find / -name gsettings > ~/gsettings_file.txt
```

From this I found `/usr/share/GConf/gsettings`, but after searching through the files, I still could not locate the workspaces config settings.

Answer (score 3):

By default the user settings are stored in `~/.config/dconf/user`. This is a binary file so you can't edit it manually.

See [Shouldn't dconf-editor and gsettings access the same database?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/416556/shouldnt-dconf-editor-and-gsettings-access-the-same-database) for some more information about what files are used by gsettings and dconf.