# Export dconf settings by reading .config/dconf of another user

Tags: gnome, login, dconf, gsettings

Is there a way to export dconf settings by reading some `.config/dconf/` tree from another user (say, `user2`), instead of the current `user1`?

I have a problem whereby I cannot log into a Gnome session with `user2`, and I found the culprit is something in its `.config/dconf/`. Evidently, I cannot export settings for `user2` since I cannot login (unless logging in via terminal and exporting ensures a proper result).
To be able to login again, I apply the solution [here](https://askubuntu.com/a/1434598/226614) whereby `user2` homedir is backed up into `user2bkp`.
Then to debug the problem, I mean to log in with `user1`, export all settings in `/home/user2bkp/.config/dconf/`, and try finding the culprit with a gradual incorporation of customizations and settings into the recreated `/home/user2/.config/dconf/`.
(Note: It is very tedious since I have to continuously log out and log in).

In addition to this question, I would need to find out all settings that were changed from the default, but that's another issue.

The root problem is described in [Gnome shell does not work with one user, but it works with a newly created one](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1432791/gnome-shell-does-not-work-with-one-user-but-it-works-with-a-newly-created-one).

**Related**:

1. [How to save GNOME settings in a file?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/984205/how-to-save-gnome-settings-in-a-file)
2. [How to run gsettings for another user Ubuntu 18.04.2 LTS](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1134453/how-to-run-gsettings-for-another-user-ubuntu-18-04-2-lts)
3. [How do I dump all the manually altered dconf / gsettings keys?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/420527/how-do-i-dump-all-the-manually-altered-dconf-gsettings-keys)
4. [How to fetch the proxy configuration of the root and other users with GSettings cmd](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1271830/how-to-fetch-the-proxy-configuration-of-the-root-and-other-users-with-gsettings)

Comment: You should be able to run `gsettings list-recursively` or `dconf dump /` as another user via `dbus-launch` - see for example [How to run gsettings for another user Ubuntu 18.04.2 LTS](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1134453/how-to-run-gsettings-for-another-user-ubuntu-18-04-2-lts) or [How to fetch the proxy configuration of the root and other users with GSettings cmd](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1271830/how-to-fetch-the-proxy-configuration-of-the-root-and-other-users-with-gsettings)

Comment: @steeldriver - That is an exact answer for the question.
But the question I posted did not represent exactly my objective (my bad!).
Directory `/home/user2/.config/dconf/` would not correspond to any user, but it would be a backup from my (`user1`) broken state, prior to recreating a clean home dir for me.
I guess the answers would then not apply.
So I would rather post a separate question, instead of altering this one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can switch the terminal to another user account using `sudo`, then export the dconf setting to a text file as indicated in the [answer you referred to](https://askubuntu.com/questions/984205/how-to-save-gnome-settings-in-a-file)

Comment: This is an exact answer for the question. But the question I posted did not represent exactly my objective (my bad!). Directory `/home/user2/.config/dconf/` would not correspond to any user, but it would be a backup from my (`user1`) broken state, prior to recreating a clean home dir for me. I guess the answers would then not apply. So I would rather post a separate question, instead of altering this one.

Comment: Then indeed accept this answer and add a question for this specific case, Of course, it would not be difficult to add "user2" as an account and then apply this approach.